# sqlite query execution when button is clicked in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a databaseHelper class. But, I want to multiply two values of each row and store it in another column while a button is clicked. I have checked my query and it works fine but I want to directly multiply the values and make change in the database when a button is click. I don't want to return any values but simply execute the query.

What I did for this is I have created a method in my database helper class. This is the method:

```
public void getTicketTotal(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.rawQuery("update ticket_table set total=quantity*item_price ",null);
}
```

and in the button click event I did this. But, it didn't multiply and store the values in the table:

```
 myDb=new DatabaseHelper(TicketActivity.this);

                myDb.getTicketTotal();
```

What to do?

Comment: try using db. execSQL instead of db.rawQuery. It is used when you are expecting some results in return

Comment: FYI, You are using `UPDATE` query then where is `WHERE ` statement ?

Comment: Why negative vote???

Comment: @Gautam ok Gautam.

Comment: `"update ticket_table set total=quantity*item_price "` , this is just a string. It won't multiply

Comment: where clause is not mendatory to update table data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the method that I was using. The solution is to use db.execSQL  instead of rawQuery. So the line of code would be:

```
public void getTicketTotal(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.execSQL("update ticket_table set total=quantity*item_price ");
}
```

and simply call it from within the activity.

Comment: good. So annoying. Sorry bro will not got this. Thanks

Comment: It's totally ok bro. :) The great part is we actually learned something.

Comment: yes bro :) happy to talk with you

Answer (score 0):

your update query is wrong. on which row you have to update total?

hope it helps

```
public void getTicketTotal(){
      SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
      db.rawQuery("update ticket_table tt set total= tt.quantity * tt.item_price" ,null);
    }
```

Comment: But this query works fine while I am separately applying it in my db table.

Comment: Why do I need a where statement here?

Comment: Because you want to update on single data right? So you need to set WHERE condition. Like "WHERE Id = 3"

Comment: I think it helps you. If this helps mark this as a right answer. Thanks Bro

Comment: @ZakiPathan where clause is not mandatory.

Comment: No bro, not single data. I want to change it on every row

Comment: So you dont need WHERE clause. You just try without where clause. I am editing my answer

Comment: Hope it helps now.

Comment: quantity and item_price are two columns in my table. Why do I need to fetch it from database and store it in my code? Why can't I simply apply the operation into my database. I mean there are already quantity and item_price data available in the table.

Comment: So you need to change the query. update ticket_table tt set total= tt.quantity * tt.item_price

Comment: I edit my answer. Please check if it works

Comment: I guess that's what I did.

Comment: Bro, u seem to miss it all. There is still two variable (quantity and item_price ) in your code. Why do I need them? I don't want to pass quantity and item_price from code. The values are already in the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135667/discussion-between-zaki-pathan-and-soumya-rauth).

Comment: Got any idea bro?